# Adding Primary List to Site Map

Tags: acumatica

I have a GI that I created to be a Primary List menu entry for the modern menu, but I cannot add it as a menu item.  It does not show up on the menu edit.  The only difference I have noticed is that the existing PL inquiries are all in CompanyID 1 and mine is in CompanyID 2.  Is there a special way to add it into the site map in company 1?  Is that why it doesn't show on Edit menu add item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured the GI as an [entry point](https://help.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=958345a7-f4df-43fd-a397-d109be7af881)?
You can use S130 Data Retrieval Analysis Documentation Training Part 1, Lesson 2 "Configuring an Inquiry as the Entry Point"
[image: Entry Point]

Comment: Thanks Ilya.  For the benefit of others, I tested both solutions and they both fixed my issue.  Your solution actually adds the row to the Lists as Entry Points automatically and is more intuitive since it can be handled directly through the GI.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to follow the PL inquiry pattern check if your screen is listed in the 'Lists as Entry Points' SM208500 screen:
[image]